# Show that C is path-connected

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $C=\{(x,y)\mid x^2-y^2\le 3, x\ge 0\}$

I want to show that $\forall x,y \in C$ there a exist a path between them in order to show that $C$ is path-connected. Any ideas how? intuitively it is very clear. it looks like an half hourglass. But I'm having a very hard time formalizing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it [star-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) with "center" $0$?

Comment: i'll add a picture

Comment: Was ment as a hint :)

Comment: Oh so can you be more concrete? what does a star-shaped with center 0 gives me?

Comment: Star-shaped means there is a point $x$ from which the line segment to any other point is contained in the set. Over this point you can connect any two point via a path. In this chase you could try $x=0$.

Comment: If you have an accurate picture, that may be $90\%$ of the answer. If you can show there's a path from every point in the region to $(0,0)$, that's about $99\%$ of the answer. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** prove that for each $P=(x,y)\in C$, there exists a path from $P$ to some point on the $y$-axis.

Comment: In particular if ($x,y)\in C$ then $[0,x]\times \{y\}\subset C.$